# node-canvas can't load a font

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

So, I'm trying to use a custom font with canvas in this way:

```js
canva.registerFont('./src/fonts/alternate-gothic-cond-atf.otf', { family: 'Alternate Gothic Cond ATF' });
ctx.font = '60px Alternate Gothic Cond ATF'
```

and get this: `(process:4992): Pango-WARNING **: 15:26:26.259: couldn't load font "Alternate Gothic Cond ATF Condensed 60px", falling back to "Sans Condensed 60px", expect ugly output.`
I tried with different fonts and works fine, so I don't know why this won't work, I also tried to reinstall the font, but nothing changed.

Edit: Since the other font I tried was .ttf I converted the file to .tff but no progress have been made.

Comment: What do you see if you try to validate the font using a thirdparty app? https://fontdrop.info/ could be an issue with the font, it might be corrupted or anything

Comment: I use the font on PS with no problem. I put the font in the site that you provide and works in every tab (Glyphs, Ligatures, OT, Text, Waterfall, Type Yourself, Data).

P.S.: I'm not good in eng so if I missunderstood something let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Currently experiencing same issue in my project, it seems you need to have the font installed on your machine for Pango to load it properly.